# Python defines my class twice on the same thread

Tags: python, class-variables, symbol-table

I had assumed that in Python if I do some

```
class A:
    print("hi")
```

this "hi" would only ever be printed more than once if I explicitly deleted A with some `del A`

In my slightly bigger project I have this code (names changed):

```
class A(ISomething):
    print(threading.current_thread())
    try:
        A.MY_DICT  # yeah, this should never ever result in anything but an error but neither should this code be run twice
        print(A.MY_DICT)
    except NameError:
        print("A.MY_DICT unknown")
    MY_DICT = {}
```

and it produces this output:

```
$ python main.py 
<_MainThread(MainThread, started 140438561298240)>
A.MY_DICT unknown
<_MainThread(MainThread, started 140438561298240)>
A.MY_DICT unknown
```

so on the same thread the same class level code gets executed twice. How is that possible when I never `del A`? The code had worked before but I don't have commits to narrow down the change that broke it.

The same code with MY_DICT instead of A.MY_DICT fails equally and as PyDev already at time of writing tells me that this will not work, I am pretty confident that there's something fishy going on.

Comment: Is there any import statement in `main.py`? Please show us the *complete* `main.py` contents.

Comment: You'll need to give more information about your code, preferably an actual runnable example.  That behavior can happen, for instance, if you import the same module twice under different names (e.g., once as a top-level module and once as part of a package).  (Also, deleting A will not cause the class definition to be re-executed.)

Comment: Is this code in separate module which is imported? or it is in some function?

Comment: The main script (the one you name on the command line) is imported as `__main__`; if you import the same file as a module, it'll get a new namespace (`main` in this case) and will be re-executed for that namespace.

Comment: @BrenBarn this is exactly the type of answers I need. Thanx. Will check that out. I failed to reproduce double-definition with some simple example of two files importing eachother several times dynamically.

Comment: Hallelujah! You are great guys! Thanx for the quick answer. Now the only thing I wonder is how I should have searched for this cause I searched for 3h. Moving `__main__` into a new file did the trick and now everything works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably importing the file under different names, *or* running it as both the `__main__` file and importing it.

When Python runs your script (the file named on the command line) it gives it the name `__main__`, which is a namespace stored under `sys.modules`. But if you then import that same file using an `import` statement, it'll be run *again* and the resulting namespace is stored under the module name.

Thus, `python main.py` where `main.py` includes an `import main` statement or imports other code that then in turn imports `main` again will result in all the code in `main.py` to be run twice.

Another option is that you are importing the module twice under different full names; both as part of a package and as a stand-alone module. This can happen when both the directory that contains the package *and* the package itself are listed on your `sys.path` module search path.